# How can we get the product id of each item in shopping cart from the session variable? in zen cart

Tags: zen-cart

How can we access the session variable for the shopping cart so that we can get the product id of each product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $products = $_SESSION['cart']->get_products();

   for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($products); $i<$n; $i++) {
      // the product's id is $products[$i]['id']
      ...
   }
```